# Issue with Apache/Linux .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am seeing too many redirects with the following .htaccess file. How do I fix this? This is PHP 7.4 on Microsoft Azure web app - Linux

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    <Files .env>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|\.svg|\.ttf)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand which one of these makes sense:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare ?